# Segmentation Fault Binary Tree Traversal

Tags: c, file, binary-tree, singly-linked-list

So i've been running and testing my code and everything seemed to have been working until i added 2 more functions for Pre-order and Post-order traversals of my tree.

The assignment was to create a linked list and tree for an input file with a random set of numbers. The linked list and tree traversals all need to be printed out in separate functions and i can't find where i went wrong.

i keep getting

Segmentation Fault (core dumped)

Here is my code:

```html
//Tristan Shepherd

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct node
{
 int num;

 struct node *next;
};

struct tree
{
 int numt;

 struct tree *left;
 struct tree *right;
};

typedef struct node LINK;
typedef struct tree branch;

int searchList(int number, LINK *head) 
{
 LINK *current;
    current = head;
    while (current != NULL) 
    {
       if (current->num == number) 
        return 1;  // Found it.
       current = current->next;
    }
    return 0;      // Did not find it.
}

LINK *insertList(int number, LINK *head)
{
 LINK *current, *temp;

 if (searchList(number, head) == 1) return head;

 temp = (LINK *)malloc(sizeof(LINK));
 temp->num = number;

 if (head == NULL)
 {
  head = temp;
  temp->next = NULL;

  return head;
 }
 current = head;
 if (current->num == number)
 {
  temp->next = current;
  head = temp;

  return head;
 }
 current = head;
 while (current != NULL)
 {
  if (current->next == NULL || current->next->num == number)
  {
   temp->next = current->next;
   current->next = temp;

   return head;
  }
  current = current->next;
 }
}

void printList(LINK *head)
{
 LINK *current;
 current = head;
 while (current != NULL)
 {
  printf("%i\n", current->num);
  current = current->next;
 }
}

LINK *freeList(LINK *head)
{
 LINK *current, *temp;
 current = head;
 while (current != NULL)
 {
  temp = current;
  current = current->next;
  free(temp);
 }
 free(head);
 head = NULL;
 return head;
}

void freeTree(branch *leaf)
{
   if(leaf != 0)
   {
       freeTree(leaf->left);
       freeTree(leaf->right);
       free(leaf);
   }
}

void insert(int new, branch **leaf)
{
    if(*leaf == 0)
    {
        *leaf = (struct tree*) malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
        (*leaf)->numt = new;
        (*leaf)->left = 0;    
        (*leaf)->right = 0;  
    }
    else if(new < (*leaf)->numt)
    {
        insert(new, &(*leaf)->left);
    }
    else if(new > (*leaf)->numt)
    {
        insert(new, &(*leaf)->right);
    }
}

void printInorder(branch *leaf)
{
   if (leaf == NULL)
     return;

   printInorder(leaf->left);

   printf("%i ", leaf->numt);
  
   printInorder(leaf->right);
}

void printPreorder(branch *leaf)
{
   if (leaf == NULL)
     return;

   printf("%i ", leaf->numt);

   printInorder(leaf->left);
  
   printInorder(leaf->right);
}

void printPostorder(branch *leaf)
{
   if (leaf == NULL)
     return;

   printInorder(leaf->left);
  
   printInorder(leaf->right);

   printf("%i ", leaf->numt);
}

int main (void)
{
 int t;
 FILE *stream = fopen("hw9.data", "r");
 LINK *head;
 branch *leaf;
 head = NULL;
 int number;
 
 while (1)
 {
  fscanf(stream, "%i", &number);
  if (feof(stream)) break;
  insert(number, &leaf);
  head = insertList(number, head);
 }

 fclose(stream);

 printf("\nPrinting List: \n");

 printList(head);

   printf("\n\nPrinting in order\n");

 printInorder(leaf);

 printf("\n\nPrinting Pre order\n");

 printPreorder(leaf);

 printf("\n\nPrinting Post order\n");

 printPostorder(leaf);

 head = freeList(head);
 freeTree(leaf);
 head = NULL;
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`branch *leaf;` is not initialized. Your code expects leaf pointers to be `NULL`. Try `branch *leaf = NULL;`

Also, it looks like `freeList` frees `head` twice which is undefined behavior.